# Pythonで特定の列を抽出しメールで送信する

Tags: python, pandas, csv, gmail

csvの日付と内容の列だけを抽出し、昨日の日付だけが含んだ列だけを抽出しメールを送信したいです。
下記のコードで記載しましたが、エラーが発生します。

ilocではdataframeがemptyだとエラーになるからだと思います。

① csvの 特定の列 だけを抽出した pandasのDataFrame を作成する
② 昨日の列だけを抽出する
③ 作成したDataFrameの 1行目と2行目(indexは0と1) に対して④~⑤の処理を行う
④ 処理対象行の 各列の列名とデータを抽出してそれぞれに改行コードを付加し、連結する
⑤ 抽出・連結した各列名＋データを、さらに改行コードで連結する
⑥ 連結したデータをメール本文として挿入し、送信する

CSVのデータ

```
日付                      内容    C     D      
2021/02/07(日) 11:10:00  test2 test3  test4
2021/02/06(土) 20:00:00  test5 test6  test7
2021/02/10(水) 15:59:00  test8 test9  test10
```

昨日分だけの列を取得してメールを送信したいです。

```
日付　　　　　　　　　　　　　内容  
2021/02/10(水) 15:59:00  test8
```

現在のコード

```
Gmail
from datetime import datetime as dt, date, timedelta
import csv
import pandas as pd
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib


today = dt.today()
(dt.strftime(today, '%Y/%m/%d'))

yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)
print(yesterday.strftime("%Y/%m/%d"))

#csvデータをdfに読み込み。 
filename = "test.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(filename,encoding='shift-jis')
#### df_i = df.set_index("A","B","C")
df_i = df[["日付","内容"]] 
print(df_i)        

df_h = df[df["日付"].str.contains(yesterday)]
print(df_h)  
#ここまで昨日のデータ上手く取得できます。      

account = "123@gmail.com"
password = "123"

to_email = "123"
from_email = "123@gmail.com"

for j in range(2):
    subject = "【TEST】"
    message = '\n'.join([f"{column}\n{data}\n" for column,data in df_h.iloc[j].iteritems()]) #### !
    print(message)
    msg = MIMEText(message)
    msg["Subject"] = subject
    msg["To"] = to_email
    msg["From"] = from_email

    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(account, password)
    server.send_message(msg)
    server.quit()
```

エラーコード

```
 File "c:/Users/test/Documents/S3/test.py", line 34, in <module>
    message = '\n'.join([f"{column}\n{data}\n" for column,data in df_h.iloc[j].iteritems()]) 
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 879, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1496, in _getitem_axis
    self._validate_integer(key, axis)
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1437, in _validate_integer
    raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

お手数おかけしますが、ご回答頂けると幸いです。

宜しくお願いします。

Comment: 質問内容だと、③~⑤の条件が成り立たないのですが、メールに入れる本文の内容は何処のデータからどのように作成されますか？

Comment: `for j in range(2):` は `for j in range(len(df_h)):` すべきでしょうね。それから、`df_h = df[df["日付"].str.contains(yesterday)]` でエラーが発生します。実際には `df_h = df[df["日付"].str.contains(yesterday.strftime("%Y/%m/%d"))]` となるはずです。

Comment: @kunif 
回答ありがとうございます。やりたいのは先ずはcsvから昨日分だけ抽出します。あれば、メール送信します。昨日分がなければ正常終了するようにしたいです。

Comment: @metropolis
回答ありがとうございます。上記の方法でも試してみます。

Comment: @metropolis 
指摘して頂いた部分を修正したところ問題なく実行されました。下記のように昨日分がない時はEmpty DataFrameと表示されメール送信されないです。またある時昨日分だけ処理されました。ありがとうございました。
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [post_time, content_url]
Index: []

Answer (score 0):

**回答の前に：**
コメントに書いた「③~⑤の条件が成り立たない」ことに関する確認事項が以下になります。

質問最初の行の「昨日の日付だけが含んだ列だけを抽出しメールを送信したい」は、「昨日の日付だけ **を** 含んだ **行** だけを抽出しメールを送信したい」の間違いでしょう。

同様に途中の「昨日分だけの列を取得してメールを送信したいです。」は、「昨日分だけの **行** を取得してメールを送信したいです。」でしょうね。

それからメール本文の内容は、質問記事には以下のように書かれていましたが：

```
日付　　　　　　　　　　　　　内容  
2021/02/10(水) 15:59:00  test8
```

「現在のコード」で示された内容はこの前の別の質問内容に沿ったものですので：

```
message = '\n'.join([f"{column}\n{data}\n" for column,data in df_h.iloc[j].iteritems()]) #### !
```

それを当てはめると以下のようになると思われます：

```
日付
2021/02/10(水) 15:59:00

内容
test8
```

**本当に欲しいメール本文の内容はどちら、あるいはまた別の内容でしょうか？**

---

**今の時点で判明している問題点：**

@metropolis さんがコメントしたように、昨日のデータを抽出するための処理が動きません。「#ここまで昨日のデータ上手く取得できます。」というのは何かの確認ミスか、質問を入力した際の転記ミスでしょう。

この行を：

```
yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)
print(yesterday.strftime("%Y/%m/%d"))
```

こちらにすることと：

```
yesterday = (today - timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
print(yesterday)
```

こちらの行は：

```
df_h = df[df["日付"].str.contains(yesterday)]
```

こうすべきでしょう：

```
df_h = df_i[df_i["日付"].str.contains(yesterday)]
```

同様に @metropolis さんがコメントしたように、「ilocではdataframeがemptyだとエラーになるからだと思います。」自身はその通りですが、その原因は「昨日の日付だけを含んだ行だけを抽出」しているので、必ずしも2行のデータがあるとは限らないのに、固定的に2行分のデータがあるものとした前回質問の回答のままループしているからです。

@metropolis さんコメントのように、こちらの行は：

```
for j in range(2):
```

こうすべきでしょう：

```
for j in range(len(df_h)):
```

それから以下の行は、今回出力しようとするメール本文の内容に合わせて変更する必要があるかもしれません：

```
message = '\n'.join([f"{column}\n{data}\n" for column,data in df_h.iloc[j].iteritems()]) #### !
```

それから、そもそも「昨日の日付を含んだ行が無い」場合を検出して、メール処理を行う前に終了するとかの対処も必要でしょう。

Comment: 前半部分は "質問への質問" になっているように見えるので、質問が曖昧に感じる部分があるのなら憶測で回答してしまうよりもコメント等でまずは明確化を求めた方が良いのかなと思いました。

Comment: 一応最初にはコメントしましたが、それだけだと何が不整合なのかということ自身が明確ではなく何か所もあって、コメントだけでやるのが大変そうなので、どの部分がどうおかしいかを指摘したつもりです。それが明らかになれば回答を修正しようと思います。

Comment: @metropolis さんから指摘して頂いた部分を修正したところ問題なく実行されました。下記のように昨日分がない時はEmpty DataFrameと表示されメール送信されないです。またある時昨日分だけ処理されました。ありがとうございました。 Empty DataFrame Columns: [post_time, content_url] Index: [] –

Comment: @kunifさん
また、丁寧に教えてくれてありがとうございます。